# First Facebook app, cant create an app id, why?

Tags: facebook, app-id

first of all, please excuse my english.

im **trying to get the app id** for my site, but when go to facebook developers page to get it, facebook always retunrs me to my own facebook page, so i cant get nothing.

Any kind of help will be apreciated.

Thank you

Trying to install this module for  joomla where it needs a facebook app id and secret.

http://www.saaraan.com/downloads/joomla-extensions/joomla-facebook-connect

http://saaraan.com/posts/item/3-creating-facebook-application-for-your-site

Comment: can you access http://developers.facebook.com?

Answer (score 1):

simply go here;

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

and you will see all your application on the left, click on the desired application and in the summary you will App ID/API Key and App Secret

Hopes it helps

Comment: +1, also make sure you're logged in as a real and verified user and not as a page or business account